# Autoloading behavior change in Rails 6.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have upgraded from Rails 6.0.3 to 6.1.3.

The new version does not seem to load files in `app/lib`, even though they were properly loaded before the upgrade.

Every documentation and StackOverflow question I found on the subject, states that `app/lib/*` should be auto loaded.

I have also tried adding these two in `config/environments/development.rb` without any change:

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('app/lib').to_s
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/lib').to_s
```

My class is called `GoodLogger`, and it is placed in `app/lib/good_logger.rb`

I was unable to find anything in the changelog to indicate how to solve this.

I should mention that I need the loaded class to be available in the configuration file itself (`config/environments/*.rb`) and to highlight that this worked in 6.0.3.

So far, the only workaround I have found is to manually require the file prior to using it, but I know this is not the rails way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any luck with this issue? I tried upgrading to rails 6.1.3 and have the same issue (i.e. my custom logger is not autoloaded)

Comment: Nope... only the workaround of manually requiring the files I need, which feels dirty. Of course, if I have a solution, I will post it.